# How can I prove KB╞ α?

Tags: first-order-logic, unification

Is correct to use ~α as rule to prove KB╞ α?

Is possible to unify sentence `~V(x,y) v S(x)` with `V(N,W)`?

```
~V(x,y) v S(x)
~V(x,y) v S(y)
~S(x) v ~S(y) v U(x,y)
V(N,W)
~U(N,W)

α = S(P)
```

Comment: Please don't just paste a whole bunch of equations into the question.  Instead, please explain them and the context.  What is the meaning of all of those propositions?  How should they be interpreted?  How do they relate to the question?  Please define all notation before first using it: it is not clear what is $\alpha$.  I encourage you to [edit] your question to make it clearer.

Comment: Showing that both $\alpha$ and $\lnot \alpha$ are proveable will show that the logic is inconsistent, thus everything can be proved in it (even incorrect statements)